# How to set padding in custom view?

Tags: android, android-custom-view

In my application I have a custom `TextView` that has some arrow on the left in `onDraw` method on `Canvas`. The problem I have is with gravity of the text, as I want it to be centered.

The only way I have found to solve this problem is to set custom left padding, so that text will be centered only in the area that it should be. In order to find out this padding I need to calculate size of the view first.

The problem is that if I put it into `onMeasure` or `onLayout` then I get stuck into the loop, so that padding is increasing until maximum value. This is happening, because `setPadding` is causing those methods to execute again.

How to solve this problem?

Comment: doesn't `setPadding` work?

Comment: `setPadding` works but, if I put it into `onMeasure` method, then this method is called again, so the padding keeps increasing recursively...

Comment: add it in your View ctor

Comment: I can't because I need to have calculated height of the view in order to set this padding.

Comment: why? why do you need the heigh? padding is padding, if you want 5px padding at the bottom you specify it as `5`, not `height - 5`

Comment: because it is related to view's height. If views height is 100px then padding is 10px, if height is 200px then padding is 20px, etc.

Comment: then try `onSizeChanged` maybe it is a better place to `setPadding`

Comment: no, I've tried it and it is also causing loop...

Comment: so try to set it conditionally: if(padding not already set) setPadding()

Comment: well I might end up with this solution, I just thought someone might know a better way.

Comment: just made a class that extends `TextView` and called `setPadding` in `onSizeChanged`, no any infinite `onSizeChanged` calling, works just fine

Answer (score 1):

If your view is static and does not change its padding while inflating, you can call `setPadding` in `onAttachedToWindow()`.

It calls just when view added to the window!